# COMPOSE - Gradient with animation?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I'm using this `drawable` as a reference :

```
<shape
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:shape="rectangle">
  <gradient
    android:type="linear"
    android:startColor="#b20811"
    android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:angle="270" />
</shape>
```

What I've got is I could create a `Brush` but I'm not sure is the same with the same angle.

```
val brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
        colors = listOf(Color(android.graphics.Color.parseColor("#b20811"),
                        Color(android.graphics.Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")),
        startY = 0f,
        endY = 1000f,
    )
```

Then I'm trying to add an animation for the gradient and I've found some approach but the problem is that the gradient is not full screen. I'm doing this

```
val transition = rememberInfiniteTransition(label = "")
    val animatedProgress by transition.animateFloat(
        initialValue = 0f,
        targetValue = 1f,
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = tween(1500, easing = LinearEasing),
            repeatMode = RepeatMode.Restart
        ), label = ""
    )
val brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
        colors = listOf(Color(android.graphics.Color.parseColor("#b20811"),
                        Color(android.graphics.Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")),
        startY = 0f,
        endY = LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp.toFloat() * animatedProgress
    )
```

And then I have my other composables

```
Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .background(brush)
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = modifier,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        ) {
          ....
         }
      }
```

How could I add animation in the gradient smooth and following the `shape` of the xml with 270º

Answer (score 1):

try to update you Y with this

```
val screenHeight = LocalConfiguration.current.screenHeightDp.dp
val density = LocalDensity.current
```

and update your brush by following for end Y

```
val brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
colors = listOf(
    Color(android.graphics.Color.parseColor("#b20811")),
    Color(android.graphics.Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"))
),
startY = 0f,
endY = with(density) { screenHeight.toPx() * animatedProgress })
```

Comment: It does get to the bottom now, but it's not that smooth, any idea?